# How to repair Xcode 11 managed profiles?

Tags: xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile

My distribution certificate was due to expire soon, so I went ahead and created a new one and revoked the soon to be expired.

I noticed that Xcode was not recreating the provisioning profiles automatically, when clicking on the info button besides the Provisioning Profile Xcode Managed Profile I saw a provisioning profile created with the last certificate even though it was already revoked.

- I tried signing out and in to my developer account in Xcode preferences.
- I tried deleting all provisioning profiles on my apple developer account.
- I tried deselecting and reselecting the Automatically manage signing checkbox on the target.

All of the above did not worked.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked was to add a new app capability. I added a new group identifier to the App Groups capability, waited for the repair message and then removed it again. 
Hope this helps.